# Virtual Environment on Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10, virtualenv

I already tried activating and deactivating the scripts on my project. I went to the directory of my project but when I tried to input 'pipenv --rm', error says 'No virtualenv has been created for this project yet! Aborted!'. I've been following a tutorial and I thought that I already have created a virtual environment. How do I create and remove one since it seems that I can't remove the test environment I've created?

Comment: "I thought that I already have created a virtual environment"—how?

Comment: What tutorial did you try? Where did you get stuck? Where is your code? What errors do you get? What VM type are you setting up? I'm asking basically everything that should already be in your post for anybody to be able to help. Without those answers you wont get much out of this post.

Comment: Thank you for the effort but I already found a solution. Just found a newer tutorial by Corey Schafer regarding this. I'll be more mindful of my questions next time. :D

Answer (score -1):

Can you 'cd' into your projects main directory then just run `pipenv install` again, then run `pipenv shell`? That will create the Pipfile & Pipfile.lock files in your project directory. I know on a Mac for example any virtualenv made will go here: ***/Users/MAINUSER/.local/share/virtualenvs/YOUR_VENV-XXXXXxx***
Personally I just delete them directly from there.